# Chilkat Docusign : Error The input is not a valid Base-64 string

Tags: delphi, docusignapi, chilkat

Delphi 10 Seattle
IntraWeb 15.0.23
Chilkat Trial

Used Chilkat (Delphi DLL) PDF File Encoding to Base64 to Encode my file.

https://www.example-code.com/delphidll/base64_pdf.asp

While parsing it to the Chilkat Delphi DLL code to request remote signing I get the below mentioned response.

https://www.example-code.com/delphidll/docusign_request_signature_via_email.asp

Please see Response code while trying to send a file through the Docusign API. I have the PDF to base64 code working and vice versa.

```
Response Status Code = 400
Response Header:
Cache-Control: no-cache
Content-Length: 226
Content-Type: application/json; charset=utf-8
Date: Wed, 27 May 2020 12:12:16 GMT
Response Body:
{
  "errorCode": "UNSPECIFIED_ERROR",
  "message": "The input is not a valid Base-64 string as it contains a non-base 64 character, more than two padding characters, or an illegal character among the padding characters. "
}
Response Body End
Request Body:
{"emailSubject":"DocuSign REST API Quickstart Sample","emailBlurb":"Shows how to create and send an envelope from a document.","recipients":{"signers":[{"email":"123@gmail.com","name":"XYZ","recipientId":"1","routingOrder":"1"}]},"documents":[{"documentId":"1","name":"C:\Doe_John.pdf","documentBase64":"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驠"}],"status":"sent"}
```

Comment: Do you think 驠 is a valid Base64 character?

Comment: The Base64string doesnt have that character when I encode the pdf file to Base64. All charaters are valid in that file. The response contains this character. This is my first time working with API's, REST, BASE64 et al.

Comment: If the below answer helped you out, be sure to upvote and accept. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your error message is very helpful in this case. Check the validity of your Base64 string -  Looks to me like a pipe and mandarin character sitting at the end of your encoded string.

```
{ "errorCode": "UNSPECIFIED_ERROR", "message": "The input is not a valid Base-64 string as it contains a non-base 64 character, more than two padding characters, or an illegal character among the padding characters. " }
```

Comment: The Base64string doesnt have that character when I encode the pdf file to Base64. All charaters are valid in that file. The response contains this character. This is my first time working with API's, REST, BASE64 et al.

Comment: As long as you are testing (and not using a private, legitimate legal document) try using this online encoder/decoder - https://www.base64decode.org/

Comment: Awesome! If you can, upvote my answer too. Happy hacking